# How to Change Color of background in Angularjs Dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I have a Poller that I have setup that has 2 files which are being queried. When new data has been found I am trying to set the color of my text background in the view but its just not happening.

If someone can solve this issue that would be great I am also welcome to suggestions to improving the structure of the code.

Service:

```
function Poller($http, $timeout) {

var projectcache = { response: [], calls: 0 };
var msgcache = { response: [], calls: 0 };
var newdata = false;
var msgdata = false;
var msgcolor = {};
var projectcolor = {};

var poller = function () {
  $timeout(poller, 10000);
  console.log("Begin Poller!");
   $http.get('http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getProjects.php')
   .then(function(r) {
     if (r.data.projects.length > projectcache.response.length) {
      newdata = true;
      projectcolor = 'green';
     } else {
      newdata = false;
      projectcolor = 'green';
     };
     angular.copy(r.data.projects, projectcache.response);
     console.log("New Data Found: " + newdata);
   });
   $http.get('http://localhost/app/controllers/php/getMessages.php')
   .then(function(m) {
     if (m.data.messages.length > msgcache.response.length) {
      msgdata = true;
      msgcolor = 'green';
     } else {
      msgdata = false;
      msgcolor = 'green';
     };
     angular.copy(m.data.messages, msgcache.response);
     console.log("New Msg Found: " + msgdata);
   });
};

poller();

return {
  projects: projectcache.response,
  messages: msgcache.response,
  newdata: newdata,
  msgdata: msgdata,
  msgcolor: msgcolor,
  projectcolor: projectcolor
};
};
```

View:

```
<li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='inbox'}" style="background-color:{{msgcolor}};" ng-click="selectTab='inbox'">Inbox</li>
<li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='projects'}" style="background-color:{{projectcolor}};" ng-click="selectTab='projects'">Projects</li>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("taskbarController", ['$scope', 'authData', '$location', 'projectsModal', 'sendMessageModal', 'Poller',
function ($scope, authData, $location, projectsModal, sendMessageModal, Poller) {

$scope.msgcolor = Poller.msgcolor;
$scope.projectcolor = Poller.projectcolor;
}]);
```

Comment: Use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead, `ng-style="{'background-color':msgcolor}"`

Comment: @wZVanG That didnt work either :/

Comment: Did i have to change my current code structure for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is to use ng-class for this.  I see you already have ng-class handling the display of your 'active' class.

If you'd like to try this approach out, I would:
1. Create css clases for each state/color you want to change to. (Can do this in external css file or between  tags you create at the beginning of your page.

```
.successBackground {
background-color:green;
}

.errorBackground {
background-color:red;
}
```

2. Modify your ng-class attributes.  Here I am assuming that success means that msgdata=true and error means that msgdata=false

Current html:

```
<li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='inbox'}" style="background-color:{{msgcolor}};" ng-click="selectTab='inbox'">Inbox</li>
<li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='projects'}" style="background-color:{{projectcolor}};" ng-click="selectTab='projects'">Projects</li>
```

Updated html:

```
<li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='inbox', successBackground:msgdata===true, errorBackground:msgdata===false}" ng-click="selectTab='inbox'">Inbox</li>
<li ng-class="{active: selectTab=='projects',successBackground:msgdata===true, errorBackground:msgdata===false}" ng-click="selectTab='projects'">Projects</li>
```

Now when your msgdata is updated, the successBackground and errorBackground are automatically updated based on the latest msgdata value.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks mate i will give this a try at the earliest time i can :) hope it sorts this out :)

Comment: The only thing is it seems like a extensive hacking style way to implement. Is there any other better structure or is this a better method.

Comment: @Elevant I would go the same route @Cliff used. The only other way is to use ng-style https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle as you cannot use expressions directly on standard `style` attribute.

Comment: @Cliff The Code works great except for the following, the Red background never initiates when False is executed.

Comment: I am unsure if my code is setup to update the tabs dynamically. it should right? i mean if the colors change on load then the colors should change on each update depending on condition?

Comment: Hi @Elevant, ahh I think I see it - typo error in my earlier response.  in the html, ng-class I had errorBackground:mgdata===false, please correct mgdata to msgdata.  Please let me know how if that resolves it :)

Comment: @Cliff Yes cliff i spotted that error and fixed it however still the same issue and i get no error. What else could be the issue. Maybe based on the Service? or do i need to add anything extra to the Controller?

Comment: Hi @Elevant,  I'm not positive, but I think it may be the controller. The lines $scope.msgcolor = Poller.msgcolor;
$scope.projectcolor = Poller.projectcolor;                                                            Would set msgcolor and projectcolor once, but on subsequent timeouts, the updates to Poller do no get assigned to your $scope variables.     If this is the case, I see two options off the top of my head:  1. If it's an option, move the $timeout out of the service and into the controller or 2. Set up a $watcher in your controller to watch for changes in Poller.

Comment: @cliff I tried moving the $timeout but i got a $timeout not defined for the service. So i dont know if that will work. How would i go about setting up a $watcher?

Answer (score 0):

@Elevant, the comment option didn't allow me to format my code snippets, so I am replying to your latest comment in this answer post.

I'm not sure if the watcher can listen to just the Poller object or if it'll need to listen to each attribute separately (msgColor, projectColor).  In my code snippet here, I'll assume we cannot and we'll need to listen to each individually.

Current code:

```
$scope.msgcolor = Poller.msgcolor;
$scope.projectcolor = Poller.projectcolor;
```

Updated with watchers:

```
$scope.$watch('Poller.msgcolor', function(newValue,oldValue) {
      $scope.msgcolor = Poller.msgcolor;
});
$scope.$watch('Poller.projectcolor', function(newValue,oldValue) {
      $scope.projectcolor = Poller.projectcolor;
);
```

Though if you still wanted to look into the option to move $timeout, I would make the following changes (not sure if this matches what you had tried).

1. In the Poller service definition remove $timeout. Updated snippet:

   ```
   function Poller($http)
   ```
2. Still in Poller, remove this line:

   ```
   $timeout(poller, 10000);
   ```
3. In the Controller add $timeout - updated snippet:

   ```
   app.controller("taskbarController", ['$scope', 'authData', '$location',      'projectsModal', 'sendMessageModal', 'Poller','$timeout'
   function ($scope, authData, $location, projectsModal, sendMessageModal, Poller,$timeout)
   ```
4. Then in the controller, you would add:

```
    $timeout(function(Poller) {
        Poller.poller();
        $scope.msgcolor = Poller.msgcolor;
        $scope.projectcolor = Poller.projectcolor;
    }, 10000);
```

I hope this helps, I haven't had a chance to test the code, so you may have to tinker around with it a bit.  Let me know how it goes!